# A Minor, but annoying niggle - Why does ASP.Net set SQL Server Guids to lowercase?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, webforms, guid, uniqueidentifier

I'm doing some client-side stuff with Javascript/JQuery with .Net controls which expose their GUID/UniqueIdentifier IDs on the front end to allow them to be manipulated. During debugging something is driving me crazy: The GUIDs in the db are stored in uppercase, however by the time they make it to the front end they're in lowercase.

This means I can't quickly copy and paste IDs into the browser's console to execute JS on the fly when devving/debugging. I have found a just-about-workable way of doing this but I was wondering if anyone knew why this behaviour is the case and whether there is any way of forcing GUIDs to stay uppercase.

Comment: How are you actually rendering the GUIDs in ASP.Net ?

Comment: They get to .Net via stored procedures and then are output using Eval inside repeater templates.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/560tzess.aspx) the Guid.ToString() method will produce lowercase string.

As to why it does that - apparently [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) states it should be this way.

> The hexadecimal values "a" through "f" are output as lower case characters and are case insensitive on input.

Also check this question on SO - [net-guid-uppercase-string-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868300/net-guid-uppercase-string-format).

So the best thing you can do is to call ToUpper() on your GUID strings, and add extension method as showed in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for the background info. Can't help wondering why MS don't enforce this at the db level too. Perhaps its for readability's sake.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an Eval template, then I'd see if you can do this via an Extension method.

something like

```
public static string ToUpperString(this Guid guid, string format = "")
{
    string output = guid.ToString(format);

    return output.ToUpper();
}
```

And then in your Eval block,

```
myGuid.ToUpperString("B")
```

Or however you need it to look.

I'm on my Mac at the moment so I can't test that, but it should work if you've got the right .Net version.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the workaround I mentioned in my question. Any idea why this is happening or what is doing it?

Comment: I think it's just taking the path of least resistance, as far as .Net is concerned, Guids are caseless and it doesn't know you're rendering it to Javascript where the case does matter.